# Error 9 when rename worksheet from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, file-rename

I'm trying to rename a worksheet from another workbook, but I'm getting Error 9

```
Dim dbWb As Workbook
'the workbook is open I saw it
Set dbWb = Workbooks.Open("Data.xlsx")  
        
Dim OldName As String
'the old name of the sheet is 1234567890                               
OldName = Activesheet.Range("A11")                  

'---HERE I have ERROR 9, the new name is 9876543210
dbWb.Sheets(OldName).Name = Activesheet.Range("G4")
```

Could you please tell me what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

First I would check if the sheet exists.

```
Dim dbWb As Workbook
Set dbWb = Workbooks.Open("Data.xlsx")

Dim OldName As String
OldName = ActiveSheet.Range("A11")

If Evaluate("ISREF('" & dbWb.Path & "\[" & dbWb.Name & "]" & OldName & "'!A1)") Then
    dbWb.Sheets(OldName).Name = ActiveSheet.Range("G4")
Else
    MsgBox "Sheet does not exist"
End If
```

If you receive the message "Sheet does not exist", the sheet does not exist. If you still get the same error, then be more specific in your code: do not just use `ActiveSheet`. Instead, refer to the workbooks using `dbWb` or `ThisWorkbook`.